# compiler.js:485 Uncaught Error: Template parse errors: Can't bind to 'ngOutletContext' since it isn't a known property of 'ng-template'

Tags: angular, angular5

I'm really not sure where to go from here. I did just try to update to Angular 5 from Angular 4, and have read that ngOutletContext was renamed ngTemplateOutletContext. However, when I search my entire project the only place that ngOutletContext is only present in files that I didn't create.
usually near  tags.

Answer (score 0):

ngOutletContext is depricated and has been removed from Angular 5

Replace **ngOutletContext** with **ngTemplateOutletContext**.

[you can use the angular update guide](https://update.angular.io/)

Comment: I had read about that but to be honest I didn't feel comfortable having to hunt down and modify every instance of ngOutletContext especially since they were all created by AngularCLI (probably should mention I'm using bootstrap on my site since a few of these files contained the out of date syntax). I did try it in a few locations Instead I just created a new empty Angular6 project, installed other dependencies (prism, bootstrap), and then copied the relevant parts of my folder structure over. A bit hackery but it worked.

Comment: I went ahead and did try manually updating the syntax on a copy of the older site Angular 5, but it did this. "ERROR in Tried to find bootstrap code, but could not. Specify either statically analyzable bootstrap code or pass in an entryModule to the plugins options."